# Unable to partition SSD

Tags: macos, bootcamp, partition, ssd

I am trying to partition my HD to install Ubuntu. I have reviewed other questions with similar issues but haven't been able to find a problem with the same symptoms.

Machine is is a Mid 2012 13-inch MacBook Air, El Capitan 10.11.4, with 70GB free space. I am using Disk Utility to create a 50GB partition.

This is the Disk Utility intent:

[image: Disk Utility Screenshot]

And this is the log when the operation fails:

[image]

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question: [this worked](http://osxdaily.com/2012/03/05/fix-partition-failed-error-mac/).

1. Reboot the Mac into Single User Mode by holding Command+S during boot
2. At command prompt type `/sbin/fsck -fy`
3. When fsck is complete, type “exit” or “reboot” to reboot
4. Boot the Mac as usual, verify the disk again in Disk Utility, and partition as usual